# Invert a value of bit in digit

Tags: java, integer, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-or

I want to invert a value of bit in digit.

The method should invert value by number of bit, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int res = flipBit(7,1);
}

public static int flipBit(int value, int bitIndex) {

    String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(value);
    char newChar = (char) (bin.charAt(bitIndex) ^ bin.charAt(bitIndex));
    
    //pseudo code
    bin[bitIndex] = newChar;    
    
    return Integer.parseInt(bin);
}
```

Comment: `return value ^ (1 << bitIndex);` ?

Comment: I have string of binary in <bin> like "111" = 7.

I need to change a bit in position <bitIndex>.

Comment: where do you have it? in source code posted value is integer

Comment: this line returns a string of binary:   String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(value);
 // bin = "111"

Comment: hm, aren't you getting it from `value` which is integer? why do you need derivative when you have originally passed value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mixing mix bitwise operations and strings will not improve the performance and reduces the redubility of code.

Assuming that `bitIndex` is zero-based, it might be done using XOR operator like that (credits to *@Iłya Bursov* since he has pointed out it earlier in the comments):

```
public static int flipBit(int value, int bitIndex) {
    if (bitIndex < 0 || bitIndex > 31) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    
    return value ^ 1 << bitIndex;
}
```

[*Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/rdO)

*A quick recap on how XOR works.*

```
1 ^ 1  =>  0
0 ^ 1  =>  1
1 ^ 0  =>  1
0 ^ 0  =>  0
```

That means zeros `0` in the bit-mask `1 << bitIndex`, created by shifting the value of `1` by the given index, will have no impact on the result while applying XOR.

Only a *single significant bit* of the *mask* would interact with the *value*: if it would encounter `1`, this bit would be turned into `0`, or if there would be `0` at the same position it would result into `1`.

*Example:*

`value = 7`, `index = 2`

```
111   -   value
 ^
100   -   bit-mask `1 << bitIndex`

011   -   result is `3`
```

`value = 0`, `index = 0`

```
000   -   value
 ^
001   -   bit-mask `1 << bitIndex`

001   -   result is `1`
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that this code is extremely faster than dealing with strings.

Comment: this is not correct, because  in case of value == 0,
it returns 2,
correct answer is 1.

Comment: @Anatoly You mean when the `value` is `0` and `bitIndex` is `0` ? Then the correct result will be `1`, and that exactly what this code will return.

Comment: @Anatoly If you would pass `1` as the argument of `bitIndex`, you'll get `2` as a result.

Comment: @BadrB More important that there's no need to mix strings with bitwise operations. Dealing with a string of `30` characters would not cause a huge performance hit. If this approach would bring an advantage in terms of readability of the code, it might be worth to pay this cost. But in this case it doesn't, a jumble of bitwise operations and strings will only create a confusion.

Comment: The problem still exists:
e.g.  value = 0, bitIndex = 1, the result is 2, correct is 1.

Comment: bitIndex needs to decrease by one position, 
like return value ^ 1 << bitIndex-1;

Comment: @Anatoly Sure, if you're using *one-based* indices, then the correct statement would be `return value ^ 1 << (bitIndex - 1);` (*don't forget the parentheses*). The code provided in the answer will produce the correct result only if indices are  *zero-based*, which is the common practice in most of the languages (and I've also specified that). If remember correctly, Basic and Matlab count indices from `1`, but neither of the languages in the C-like family does so.

Answer (score 0):

This solution refers to:

> I have string of binary in *bin* like "111" = 7. I need to change a bit in position *bitIndex*.

Currently *bitIndex* is zero-based and counted from the front of the string. (This might not be desired and could be changed with the use of `bitIndex = binaryText.length() - 1 - bitIndex;`)

```java
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(7);
        int bitIndex = 2;
        System.out.println("Original string:         " + bin);
        System.out.println("String with flipped bit: " + flipBit(bin, 2));
        try {
            System.out.println("Flipping using number:   " + flipBitViaNumber(bin, 2));    
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.err.println("Oops! Not a number: " + bin);
        }
        System.out.println("Flipping via char array: " + flipBitViaCharArray(bin, 2));
    }
    
    public static String flipBit(String binaryText, int bitIndex) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(binaryText.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < binaryText.length(); i++) {
            if (i == bitIndex) {
                 sb.append(binaryText.charAt(i) == '1' ? '0' : '1');
            } else {
                sb.append(binaryText.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String flipBitViaNumber(String binaryText, int bitIndex) 
        throws  NumberFormatException {

        int value = Integer.parseInt(binaryText, 2);
        int pattern = 1 << (binaryText.length() - 1 - bitIndex);
        value = value ^ pattern;
        return Integer.toBinaryString(value);
    }
    
    public static String flipBitViaCharArray(String binaryText, int bitIndex) 
        throws  NumberFormatException {

        char[] chars = binaryText.toCharArray();
        chars[bitIndex] = chars[bitIndex] == '1' ? '0' : '1';
        return new String(chars);
    }    
}
```

```
Original string:         111
String with flipped bit: 110
Flipping using number:   110
Flipping via char array: 110
```

**Additional information**

A Java *int* consists of 32 bits, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html. Java uses the [*two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) as binary representation. Bitwise operations on ints are handled on the Java stack with particular bytecodes which are very fast as neither objects nor method invocations are used.

Answer (score -2):

How about:

```
String bin = Integer.toBinaryString( value );
char newChar = (char) (bin.charAt(bitIndex) ^ bin.charAt(bitIndex));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder( bin );
sb.setCharAt( bitIndex, newChar );
return sb.toString();
```

Comment: shouldn't we expect `0` (integer) from `(bin.charAt(bitIndex) ^ bin.charAt(bitIndex))` , no matter which value is at that position? And  `(char) 0` is not same as `'0'`?

Comment: I tried this, and <sb> suddenly cuts value:

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bin);
sb.setCharAt(bitIndex, newChar);
bin = sb.toString();        // sb becomes "11", loses one bit. should be  "110"